# Chrome Extension: Firestore (8.10.0): Connection WebChannel transport errored

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension

I am using firebase with firestore in a Chrome Extension. Now and then I get this error message. I suspect it is triggered when the computer enters sleep mode for a certain amount of time:

> Firestore (8.10.0): Connection WebChannel transport errored

I use the following setup:

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig.app);
const firebaseUi = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
firebase.firestore().settings({ 
    useFetchStreams: false,
    experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
    experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true,
    merge: true
});
```

None of those settings have worked out for me. Not alone, not mixed. I need to use the option "merge" to avoid another error. I also can't catch this error with try { } catch {}, which is rather unsatisfying since this issue throws a visible error in the Chrome Extensions page.

I am quite sure this is due to snapshot listeners that get disconnected. I tried to catch the error there with a function as a second argument to log the error:

```
ref.onSnapshot(
    (snapshot) => {
        ...
    },
    (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    }
);
```

Sadly, this was as unsuccessful as well. Any ideas on how to catch that error? I've never experienced an issue functionality-wise.

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: No. I ended up monkey patching by changing the library.

Comment: What library did you use?

Comment: This depends on your implementation. The function that throws the error is located within the firebase Cloud Firestore SDK.

Answer (score -2):

Firebase 9 is solved this problem

Comment: I currently can't verify this since I would need to change to the modular system.